# What is the cause of this retain cycle? and is there a way to force memory to be deallocated?

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-graphics, opentok

I've been searching for a solution to this problem, without success, for sometime.

I use [OpenTok Video Framework](http://opentok.github.io/opentok-ios-sdk/index.html) to publish a video stream from the device camera to an online service. I use their publish/unpublish methods as documented.

**Problem:** The memory allocated by `[GLVideoProcessor createFrameBuffers]` never gets deallocated, even when its parent VC is deallocated and the framework's unpublish method is called(and delegated nil'ed).

**Question 1:** Without being able view the framework's .m files, is there a way to force memory to be released?

**Request 2:** Any other advice about how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Occurs in:
Xcode 4.6 & Xcode 5
iOS6 & iOS7

Instruments: The doPublish method alloc's OTPublisher and initiates the stream.
[image: Overview]

Multiple Instances of Publish/Unpublish being called and never being deallocated. 
[image: Shows GLVideo staying alive]

ARM view of `[GLVideoProcessor createFrameBuffers]`

[image]

ARM view of `[GLVideoProcessor createFrameBuffers]` + Backtrace
[image]

Comment: Why are you posting here and not on http://tokbox.com/forums/ios/? Looking at the URL for the documentation for this, there is virtually nothing to go on, and you have given us no code on how you set this object up. Look in the .h files and see if there is some exposed property, one idea. My guess is that you are holding on to a reference to some object somewhere that is blocking the memory dealloc, but its obviously just a guess.

Comment: Got an answer below. Hopefully it helps some other people here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my name is Song and I work at TokBox. Thank you for posting the memory problem. We have identified the cause of this bug and a fix will be coming out next week.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I look forward to the fix. Out of curiosity, tokbox, as I understand it, makes its money by providing storage and the backend infrastructure. Why not open source your client side implementation? I'd be happy to contribute, as I'm sure a lot of more talented developers than myself would.

Comment: This bug is fixed and scheduled to go out this week! Open sourcing our technology is currently not an option for us. Laying the infrastructure and process conventions for accepting patches outside the company while driving a growing internal engineering team is non-trivial. There's a lot of planning and documentation needed to make open source work. If anything I'm confident that the number of inbound support queries would increase because of questions about the code itself, and this would slow down the response time for developers that truly have an issue we should address quickly.

Comment: TL;DR: Open sourcing the project would slow the development down. If you need support, we're all ears and want to make that experience the best it can be (and the forums are public so you can hold us accountable). Hope these answers addresses your concerns!